# How can I delay a POST request from a user form until AFTER a webhook POST from Stripe is received?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, stripe-payments

I want users to pay a fee before a POST request from a front end form is processed. I have a Stripe webhook that works fine on the backend, but I'm not sure how to delay the front end posting of the form until after the payment confirmation is received.

In the code below, right now, `createTour` and `createTourPay` run at the same time. I would like for `createTourPay` to execute first, and the `createTour` only triggers after Stripe posts to my application from the webhook. How can I achieve this?

**Controller File (webhook):**

```
exports.webhookCheckout = (req, res, next) => {
  const signature = req.headers['stripe-signature'];
  let event;
  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
      req.body,
      signature,
      process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET
    );
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).send(`Webhook error: ${err.message}`);
  }
  if (
    event.type === 'checkout.session.completed' &&
    event.line_items.name === 'New Job Purchase'
  ) {
    res.status(200).json({ recieved: true });
    // Somehow, I want this to trigger the execution of the POST request in my front end JS file.
  } else {
    if (event.type === 'checkout.session.completed')
      createBookingCheckout(event.data.object);
    res.status(200).json({ recieved: true });
  }
};
```

**Front end JS file:**

```
export const createTourPay = async myForm => {
  try {
    // 1) Get the checkout session from API response
    const session = await axios(`/api/v1/tours/tour-pay`);
    const complete = 1;
    // console.log(session);
    // 2) Create checkout form + charge the credit card
    await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      sessionId: session.data.session.id
    });
  } catch (err) {
    // console.log(err);
    showAlert('error', err);
  }
};

export const createTour = async myForm => {
  try {
    const startLocation = {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [-10.185942, 95.774772],
      address: '123 Main Street',
      description: 'Candy Land'
    };

    const res = await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${myForm._boundary}`
      },
      url: '/api/v1/tours',
      data: myForm
    });

    if (res.data.status === 'success') {
      showAlert('success', 'NEW TOUR CREATED!');
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        location.assign('/');
      }, 1500);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    showAlert('error', err.response.data.message);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadly: don't do this. Instead, you in fact *should* create some pending/unpaid version of the "tour" (or any other product/service) in your system, then attach the unique id (eg: `tour_123`) to the Checkout session when you create it, either using the `client_reference_id` ([doc](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-client_reference_id)) or `metadata` ([doc](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-metadata)):

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  // ... other params
  client_reference_id: 'tour_123',
  metadata: { tour_id: 'tour_123' },
});
```

Then you'd use the webhook to *inspect* those values, and update your own database to indicate the payment has been made and that you can [fulfill the order](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders#fulfill) to the customer (ship product, send codes, allow access to service etc).

If you really want to proceed with a more synchronous flow, you can use [separate auth and capture](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-capture_method) to sequence your customer experience and [capture the funds later](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/capture-later#capture-funds) after authorizing and creating your tour entity.

**Edit: a note about security**

You should never trust client-side logic for restricted operations like creating a "paid" tour. A motivated user could, for example, simply call your `/api/v1/tours`  create endpoint without ever going through your payment flow. Unless you validate a payment and track that state on your server you won't be able to know which of these had actually paid you.

Comment: Ah, interesting. So create the tour first, pass the unique ID into the checkout, then update a field in the DB to confirm payment. On the front end, I could just set it up to only display tours where “paid: true” or something like that. Do I understand correctly, generally speaking?

Comment: That's right! I just added a note about client-side logic & security, too. You really *need* to manage this unpaid/paid state on your back end to make it secure, otherwise a bad actor could manipulate your client code to make the tour creation request without paying.

Comment: And yea, you could have your client retrieve a list of tours from your back end on `GET /api/tours` and it could be a list of just paid ones, or paid and pending etc. That's a product decision up to you. Remember a user might cancel or close their browser during Checkout without ever paying, so you'll have some pending items to manage. You could, for example, show those unpaid tours in a customer dashboard and a link to go to Checkout again to pay for them (without creating a new one this time!), say if their browser crashed or internet dropped the first time.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the insight!! :) I was able to set it up to work as suggested. I haven’t messed with “pending” items yet, but for now, I have the listing created in the database first, and upon successful creation, the stripe checkout window is opened for the unique listing ID. Very cool stuff! Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Quite welcome -- glad to hear it helped you! :D